# Home icon is not showing correctly using font awesome

Tags: fonts

i have added this class in css classes `fa fa-lg fa-home` in appearance > menu >secondary menu home.

but its icon is not showing correctly using font awesome, i want to show only icon instead of home text on both menus i.e primary top menu and secondary menu home button

The page I need help with: https://testfellow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your the icon is being output outside of the anchors. To fix this issue, add another class, for example `my-class` to the menu classes. Now, try to position the icon absolutely, and fix the padding:

```
.fa.my-class::before {
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     top: 50%;
     transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.fa.my-class {
     margin-left: 10px;
     padding-left: 10px;
     position: relative;
}
```

Comment: i have followed as u told;i m having alignment issue i want to put home icon in center when i see this icon on mobile it does not show properly pls check this link https://testfellow.com

Comment: Have you added this CSS to your custom CSS? I can't see any style being added to your stylesheet.

Comment: I've also added a `position:relative` to the styles. That should fix the issue on mobile too.

Comment: yes i have added css to custom css

Comment: everything is fine but the icon on navigation menu is not aligned in the center check the link now i have added the same